# Batik SVG to PDF no text

Tags: pdf, svg, debian, batik

I have a crazy issue that's driving me insane :)

Using highcharts export to PDF feature, it generates the graph data but without text.

I am using Debian 6 and installed the libbatik-java which had a transcode issue when it came to exporting to PDF. After some reading the solution found on stackoverflow was to download batik from apache's site which I done and can now export to PDF.

However the text isnt shown as it appears to be rendered off screen because when I edit one the x/y values it can then see the text.

I works perfectly fine when exporting to PNG or JPG.

I also copied the SVG to another server which is running AIX and ran batik command there and it converted to PDF without issues.

I also tried copying the batik DIR from our AIX box to the Debian box but still have the same problem.

Not sure what else I can do :(

Any help would be appreciated.